# jQuery show/hide select and button

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I can show different buttons once you click it. Example:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="button1">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button2" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button3" style="display: none;">

<select id="whatever">
<option id="1">1</select>
<option id="2">2</select>
<option id="3">3</select>
</select>

<select id="whatever2" style="display: none;">
<option id="1">1</select>
<option id="2">2</select>
<option id="3">3</select>
</select>
```

I want button1 to show select id "whatever" and button 2 to hide select id="whatever" and show "whatever2" and button 3 same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet? Read the jQuery docs on .show(), .hide(), and .click()?

Comment: I tried, nothing worked

Comment: Show us what you've tried, @Timmy6118CP.

Comment: Ton of examples in Stackoverflow itself.

Comment: @canon i dont have it anymore

Comment: Flag for close. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button1

```
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#whatever" ).show();
});
```

button2

```
$( "#button2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#whatever" ).hide();$( "#whatever2" ).show();
});
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
   $(this).hide().siblings('input:eq(0)').fadeIn();
})
```

Check this:    [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNXCV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
   $("#selectId").show();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('whatever').style.display = 'block';" id="button1">
```

through jQuery

```
$('#yourbuttonId').click(function()
  $('#whatever').show();
});
```